# Can you convert a LightSail Instance / Snapshot to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

We spun up a box on LightSail because of its simplicity but now we're looking to do some more complicated things. Is there a way to take a snapshot from LightSail and spin up an ec2 instance with a LightSail image.

Our end goal is to just get an ec2 image up with the image we worked with under LightSail.

The API docs for LightSail don't seem to mention anything close to this. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe this is supported at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure when it got added (other answer may have been right at the time), but now there's a way to export a Lightsail snapshot to EC2 ; select manage on the instance, then create snapshot; on the list of snapshots, click on the 3-vertical-dot menu, and then export to EC2

Comment: awesome, I"ll switch the best answer!